# How make method decorators instance the object in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, api, lambda

I have been developing a lambda project and we are using [lambda-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-api) package. Then I have defined some decorators called `Get` and `Post` to map a route into lambda api object. With these decorators I have defined a class called ProductApi to hold methods that can be configured using those decorators and passing a route path. It works fine.

The problem is that when I have a class like `ProductApi` the constructor is never called and if I want to add some dependencies (like a Service or a Repository) it will never be defined. In this example, the `/health` route works fine because it does not use anything from the object instance, but other routes does not.

How can I make sure that the constructor will be called and define the service instance?

```
const api = createAPI();

function Get(path: string) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        api.get(path, descriptor.value.bind(target));
    };
}

function Post(path: string) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        api.post(path, descriptor.value.bind(target));
    };
}

class ProductApi {
    private someValue: string;

    constructor(private readonly productService: IProductService = new ProductService()) {
        // this scope does not execute
        this.someValue = "some value";
    }

    @Get('/health')
    async healthCheckr(req: Request, res: Response) {
        console.log(`Executing -- GET /health`);
        // this.someValue does not exists here
        return res.status(200).json({ ok: true });
    }

    @Get('/products')
    async getProducts(req: Request, res: Response) {
        console.log(`Executing -- GET /products`);
        const data = this.productService.getProductsFromService(); // error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProductsFromService')
        return res.status(200).json(data);
    }

    @Post('/products')
    async postProducts(req: Request, res: Response) {
        console.log(`Executing -- POST /products`);
        const product = this.productService.saveProduct('Drums', 1200); // erro: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'saveProduct')
        return res.status(201).json(product);
    }
}

export const lambdaHandler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent, context: Context): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    console.log('SCOPE lambda');
    return await api.run(event, context);
};
```

Note: I don't want to use frameworks, I just want a easy way to configure routes on the lamda api instanmce.

Comment: Are you using legacy decorators or draft decorators?

Comment: @Thomas the idea of the decorators is to configure the api routes, not execute them. It does not execute, I can see the logs. It executes when the api.run hits on the lambda handler and using the event argument it knows what route it will execute. Async will be added in the future - just ignore for now.

Comment: @Dimava I am not sure, I just enable experimentalDecorators on my tscripts and I did this code.

Comment: @FelipeOriani what is your typescript version then? Latest 5.0 ?

Comment: Do you have a DI container, or how do you want this class to be instantiated and the dependencies injected?

Comment: No, I don't have it at this moment, I just want to make sure the constructor will be executed before hiting the method. I will try to prepare the an working example and post the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike in C#, in JS a "method" is just a function stuck to an object. You can easily put it in a variable or stick it to another object. This basically defines what `this` is inside that "method".
And a "class" constructor is just a function that creates a new object and tells it, "if someone's looking for some property that you don't have, forward them to my `prototype` object over here." Then it executes the code inside the constructor with that object as `this`.

That is JS' prototypal inheritance in a nutshell, and even if JS has received a `class` keyword in the meantime, that's what still happens behind the scenes.

Why am I explaining this?

Because decorator are working on that prototype object. This line here `api.get(path, descriptor.value.bind(target));` takes the method from that prototype, permanently binds the prototype object as `this` *(so the resulting function will only know the prototype object and never ever see any real instance)* and uses the bound function as a callback for that route.

So currently, even if that class would magically be instantiated (by whom; I don't know) the function that you've passed to the route will have no knowledge of that.

imo. Your decorator should look more like this:

```
function Get(path: string) {
    return function (target: any, methodName: string) {
        if(typeof target[methodName] !== "function"){
          throw new Error("you need to use this decorator with a method.");
        }

        const Class = target.constructor;

        api.get(path, (req: Request, res: Response) => {
          const instance = diContainer.getInstance(Class); // or new Class();
          return instance[methodName](req, res);
        });
    };
}
```

Sidenote: Dimava brought up this topic; these are legacy decorators. TS adapted them long before there was a spec for decorator in JS. Now there is one and it significantly differs from these legacy decorators and TS has finally implemented the spec in V5. You (and me) should get updated on the new syntax and adopt it, because this syntax will probably be deprecated pretty soon.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Thomas. What DI container do you recommend in this case?

Comment: @FelipeOriani I don't use them in JS/TS. But I'm familiar with these patterns/constructs from .NET; the controller, the DI in the constructor, the route attributes. I just assumed, that's what you're familiar with, that's what you try to replicate in node. imo. I don't see the advantage of `@Get("path") someFunc(rec, res) { ... }` over `api.get("path", (rec, res) => { ... });` and if you really want ioc, that can be as simple as a shared `Map<T, ()=>T>`.

Comment: Same, I am a 20 years C# developer working with TS since last month. I am trying to make it easy to use and test, via get/post decorators and export the Api class. Then I could have a configured lambda-api and test it via DI. Thanks for answering it @Thomas, I will make some experiments.

Comment: It worked as I expected, thank you very much. I am not sure if it is a good practice for a lambda project in nodejs but it works similar to asp.net. For every request, I have a new instance of my `ProductApi` class resolving all the dependencies. Now I just need a DI container, not sure if I am going to use it yet. Thanks @Thomas.

Comment: And also thanks for the explanation for prototype, Now I realize why it was not working before.

Answer (score 1):

You need to first store metadata about how to bind routes, and then apply that on class creation

https://tsplay.dev/mbvA4m (runnable)

```
import type { Request, Response } from 'lambda-api'

type LambdifiedProto = {
  '_lambdifiedGetters'?: Record< /* path */ string, /* propertyKey */ string>
}

function Get(path: string) {
  return function <K extends string, T extends (req: Request, res: Response) => Promise<any>>(
    proto: Record<K, T>, propertyKey: K, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>
  ): void {
    let lproto = proto as LambdifiedProto;
    if (!Object.hasOwn(lproto, '_lambdifiedGetters')) {
      // create or clone from protoproto
      lproto._lambdifiedGetters = { ...lproto._lambdifiedGetters }
    }
    lproto._lambdifiedGetters![path] = propertyKey
    console.log(`registered getter ${propertyKey} on path ${path}`)
  }
}

function Lambda<C extends new (...a: any[]) => any>(klass: C) {
  return class Lambdified extends klass {
    constructor(...a: any[]) {
      super(...a);
      let getters = (klass.prototype as Lambdified)._lambdifiedGetters
      for (let [path, propertyKey] of Object.entries(getters)) {
        console.log('register api: ', { path, propertyKey, this: this })
        // api.register(path, (q, s) => this[propertyKey](q, s))
      }
    }
  }
}

@Lambda
class ProductApi {
  me = 'ProductApi'
  @Get('./health')
  @Get('./v1/health')
  async healthCheckr(req: Request, res: Response) {
    console.log(`Executing -- GET /health`);
    // this.someValue does not exists here
    return res.status(200).json({ ok: true });
  }
}

console.log('...create start...')

new ProductApi()
```